# How to boot to Windows 7 after installing Lion on my OS X (using rEFit)

Tags: windows-7, windows, macos, osx-lion, multi-boot

I just installed the Lion upgrade to OS X.

Now, when I boot i don't get any options to boot to Windows 7 as i did before the upgrade.

I have rEFit installed. What can I do?

When I installed the OS's, I did it this way:

- Installed OS x
- Installed rEFit
- Made a new partition and installed Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what I did. I found the bootcamp software and installed it. It regonized my Windows 7 installation and i could boot to Win7.

Answer (score 0):

If you did a manual install of rEFit, have a look here:

http://refit.sourceforge.net/doc/c1s4_osxupdates.html

Sounds like it got disabled.  The above link should get you going again.

Comment: I did not work. The problem is that rEFit does not support the new Lion update. But can i somehow install Bootcamp and boot to windows this way?

Comment: Bootcamp will most likely result in you needing to reinstall Windows, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Hold the option key on boot, eventually it should come up with a refit-style list of all bootable drives.   if your win7 drive is there (and it should be, unless something else has changed.) just double-click on it or arrow key over to it and hit enter.